# "Let $G \cong H$. $G$ is planar graph $\Leftrightarrow$ $H$ is planar graph."

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-isomorphism

"Let $G \cong H$. In this case $G$ is planar graph $\Leftrightarrow$ $H$ is planar graph." If this proposition true, prove that. If false, give an example.

This question in my exercise book. I curious solve of this quesiton. I know if a graph is planar that graph edge's don't intersect. But I can't explain clearly this proof. Can you help me? Thank you. (My english is not good, if I said wrong something sorry for that)

Comment: you can use the same graph embedding but change the names of the vertices with the graph isomorphism.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your idea. Can you explain more than? Is proposition true? @Onir

Comment: Almost always when two things are isomorphic it means that they are pretty much the same objects but with different names

Comment: Thank you. @Onir